# KohanaPHP 3 core throwing an error

Tags: php, kohana

I'm getting a

`ErrorException [ 2 ]: fopen(Unknown) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory ~ SYSPATH/classes/kohana/core.php [ 1213 ]`

after I finish the 'install'. It's the same problem as featured [here](http://forum.kohanaphp.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=3727) , but I still don't find a solution to it. Anyone with experience with this ?

Comment: yes, version 3 but it only throws an error without a stack trace

Comment: found the bug, it appears when you try to access a resource that cannot be autoloaded, either .htaccess misconfiguration or some "autoload expecting" class ( in my case Model_Article instead of Model_Articles )

Comment: still doesn't work on the server it didn't work on before, but I had the same error as defined in the comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer finally; Kohana PHP 3 used to have a bug in Core class, didn't report errors properly. If you get this problem, just download the most recent files from GitHub:

http://github.com/kohana/core